# jquery slice div animation (curtain style)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slice

I'm actually almost done, just can't figure the last part yet...

What I want is actually what happens exactly at the middle of the animation in my jsfiddle (see below), I want the "Hi" to be positioned at the middle and cut in two as the divs start moving.

I can't seem to get the initial positioning right.

Here's what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/WwwCn/

**HTML**

```
<div id="curtain1">
    <div><h1 style="color:#FFF">Hi</h1></div>
</div>
<div id="curtain2">
    <div><h1 style="color:#FFF">Hi</h1></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#curtain1, #curtain2 {
    background: #333;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#curtain1 div {
    position:relative;
    left: 50%;
    color:#eee;
    text-align:center;
}
#curtain2 div {
    position:relative;
    right: 50%;
    color:#eee;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$('#curtain1').delay(1000).animate({
    left: '-100%'
},4000);
$('#curtain2').delay(1000).animate({
    right: '-100%'
},4000);
```

Anyone has an idea as how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you need to give the curtains a 50% width and position them left and right.

```
#curtain1,#curtain2 { width:50%; }
#curtain1 { left:0; }
#curtain2 { right:0; }
```

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwwCn/2/).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Do you have any suggestions as how to avoid the horizontal scroll-bar to appear when the animation starts? I tried wrapping both curtain divs into a single div with 100% width and height and overflow:hidden, but it doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: Add a position:relative; (or fixed, or absolute, depending on needs) to the container. Since the curtains are positioned absolutely, they are out of the document flow unless their parent is positioned.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `overflow:hidden`. It is covering the left-half of the H.

[jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/WwwCn/4/)

I also added a `top` position for each item you specify `left`/`right` on, because Firefox has a tendency of boinking if you don't specify both X & Y values.

**EDIT**

Cleaned it up a little bit by use of class and proper `position` attributes for the `#curtain1` and `#curtain2`.

[Second updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwwCn/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it seems like the jsfiddle isn't working though? Maybe it needs the curtain div width to be set at 50%?

Comment: which jsFiddle? i tested both on Chrome, Firefox, and IE. i also just updated them to include a wrapper around the curtains with `overflow:hidden`, to prevent the horizontal scrollbar you mentioned in the accepted post.

Comment: Hmm, I probably didn't explain myself right in what I wanted to achieve exactly, this is what I wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/WwwCn/6/

Comment: oh you just wanted to start Hi in the middle! i thought that u wanted to move it from the left to the center, then split it. my bad.